# Looping an AnyHashable Dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, hashable

I am trying to loop the information that I got from a Http response, but I am having trouble accessing the data.
this is currently the information I am trying to Loop:
[image]

I was trying to use a For to access the different elements of the response but cant figure out how to access the elements inside the dictionary, this is the code I am using:

```swift
var dictionaryMessage: NSMutableDictionary?
            do {
                if let data = result?.data(using: .utf8) {
                    dictionaryMessage = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSMutableDictionary
                    if(dictionaryMessage?["precios"] != nil){
                        var element = dictionaryMessage?["precios"]
                        for (index, element) in element![0]{
                            print("index" + index + "element:" + element)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                //error handling
            }
```

I was hoping to find the correct method to access this data, because at the moment I am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: This isn't an Array, it's a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var element = dictionaryMessage!["precios"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in the code. Swift is a strong typed language, with `NS...` collection types you get unspecified `Any(Object)` and you have to conditionally downcast all types.

The value for key `precios` is an **array** with `String` keys and `Int` values, so the enclosing dictionary `dictionaryMessage` is `[String:[[String:Int]]]`

```
var dictionaryMessage : [String:[[String:Int]]]?
do {
    if let data = result?.data(using: .utf8) {
        dictionaryMessage = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:[[String:Int]]]
        if let precios = dictionaryMessage?["precios"] {
            for item in precios {
                for (index, element) in item {
                    print("index: \(index) element: \(element)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

or if there is only one element in the array

```
do {
    if let data = result?.data(using: .utf8) {
        dictionaryMessage = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:[[String:Int]]]
        if let precios = dictionaryMessage?["precios"]?.first {
            for (index, element) in precios {
                print("index: \(index) element: \(element)")
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```